# How to render a JPopupMenu immediately?

Tags: java, swing, scala, jpopupmenu

I am implementing a game where the player can place a piece by right-clicking on the game board and choosing one of several pieces from a popup menu. In "hot seat" mode, both players are using the same UI, so different menu instances are shown.

The problem is that calling the `JMenuItem.show` method causes the wrong menu to be rendered first, then quickly replaced by the correct menu (you can tell because the icons used in menu entries have different background colors for each player).

I can exacerbate the problem by adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` immediately after calling `show`. Then on right-click I see the previously shown, other player's menu (or only the background of correct size, on the very first invocation) for one second followed by a refresh of the menu whereupon the correct pieces are rendered.

Is there a way to render the correct menu immediately?

Not sure if this is important, but there are no calls to `repaint` anywhere in the click processing callback in the `isPopupTrigger` branch.

**Edit: adding an example in Scala**

```
import java.awt.event._
import javax.swing._

object MenuDemo extends App {
  val frame = new JFrame()
  frame.setTitle("Menu Demo")
  frame.setSize(600, 400)
  frame.setLocation(0, 0)
  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter {
    override def windowClosing(e: WindowEvent): Unit = System.exit(0)
  })

  var index = 0
  def tick() = index = (index + 1) % 2

  def makeMenuItem(i: Int) = {
    val menuItem = new JMenuItem("item in menu #" + i)
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
      override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent): Unit = tick()
    })
    menuItem
  }

  def makeMenu(i: Int) = {
    val menu = new JPopupMenu()
    menu.add(makeMenuItem(i))
    menu
  }

  val menus: Seq[JPopupMenu] = Seq(0, 1).map(i => makeMenu(i))

  def showMenu(e: MouseEvent): Unit = {
    menus(index).show(e.getComponent, e.getX, e.getY)
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }

  val panel = new JPanel()
  panel.add(new JLabel("right click me"))

  panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter {
    override def mousePressed(e: MouseEvent): Unit = {
      if (e.isPopupTrigger) showMenu(e)
    }

    override def mouseReleased(e: MouseEvent): Unit = {
      if (e.isPopupTrigger) showMenu(e)
    }
  })

  frame.getContentPane.add(panel)
  frame.setVisible(true)
}
```

**Edit 2**

I'm only seeing this behavior on a Mac. On Windows the delay happens before the menu is shown.

Comment: Please consider posting an [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `Is there a way to render the correct menu immediately?` - this is the default behaviour, the problem is with your code. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for a working example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the menu items might be getting reorganized after `show` method is called. For instance `javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener.popupMenuWillBecomeVisible` might be resetting the menu items depending on the context.

If this is the case you can avoid the flicker by having two different instances of popup menu and calling show on one of them depending on context.

Comment: That's exactly what I had: two menus, no reorganization (except enabling and disabling of individual entries).